# Sending email using Laravel but couldn't using Linode Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel, linode

I tried to send an email using Laravel, but I could not email using Linode Shared Hosting.

> Connection could not be established with host
> "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect
> to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to combat spam, Linode blocks SMTP on new accounts by default. There is a procedure you can follow to set up your account properly and then request that SMTP be unblocked.

See [this support article](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19082/i-just-created-my-first-linode-and-i-cant-send-emails-why) for the steps you need to follow.